# 'NA' stands for 'North America', NOT a NaN / Null

Tags: python, pandas

I have a value in my pandas df that is 'NA', as a string. **It is NOT a null/NaN.** In this case 'NA' stands for 'North America', but it's a code, 'EU' is for 'Europe' for example.

`.fillna(value='NA')` is used after `pd.read_csv` to correct this. Simple enough for one Jupyter Notebook. But what happens when you then export this data to a new CSV, and upload it again into a different Jupyter Notebook?

Do I need to `.fillna(value='NA')` all over again? Or is a there a more lasting solution?

Any hacks? I'm guessing something to do with Regex? Or perhaps it is something to do with how Pandas is set up?

Comment: `df = df.replace('NA', np.nan)` ?

Comment: Please clarify the question.  Additionally, please update the question what with *you* have tried / researched before asking for help; and *why* it’s not working as expected.

Comment: @user17242583 But I don't want NaN. NA stands for North America, not a null.

Comment: @S3DEV done so.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'your_path', na_values= "", keep_default_na= False)
```

this changes the list that pandas uses to interpret Nan values making it recognize Nan values solely by an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

As [@user17242583 said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250593/when-na-is-a-string-not-null/70252018#comment124183849_70250593), try `np.nan`, like:

```
MY_DICT = {'A':['NA', 456], 'B':[111, 400]}
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(MY_DICT)

print('before:')
print(df)
print('type(df.loc[0,\'A\']):' ,type(df.loc[0,'A']))
print('\nafter: ')
df = df.replace('NA', np.nan)
print(df)
print('type(df.loc[0,\'A\']):' ,type(df.loc[0,'A']))
```

outputs:

```
before:
     A    B
0   NA  111
1  456  400
type(df.loc[0,'A']): <class 'str'>

after: 
       A    B
0    NaN  111
1  456.0  400
type(df.loc[0,'A']): <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: This would work if I wanted a NaN. But NA isn't null. It's a string, a value. I don't want it to keep ending up as a null every time I pd.read_csv.

Comment: oh i see. i dind't understood the question then, seems to be that other guys also didn't. your clarifications helped.